# Обработка кнопок в потоке

Tags: android, java

Доброе время суток.

Задача следующая:
Есть устройство, которое работает под андроидом. Экран без touchscreen, но есть физические кнопки. Код нажатой кнопки передается по UART в устройство. В зависимости от нажатой кнопки на экране должны выполнятся определенные действия: выбор (подсвечивание) картинки (текста), запуск новой активности, воспроизведение звука, закрытие активности и т.д.

На данный момент получение и обработка принятых данных через UART выполняется в потоке, который создается в главной активности. При создании следующей активности поток продолжает работать. Но при получении кода нажатой кнопки необходимо выполнять действия, которые должны относится уже к вновь созданной активности. А как это сделать? (Если я правильно понимаю, то поток связан с активностью, в которой он создан.)

Я так думаю, что у меня неправильная структура самого проекта. Какую структуру в такой ситуации необходимо использовать?

**Обновление**

Как я уже писал, возможности, для использования Service, наверное, есть. Я новичок в программировании на яве под андроид. Вот я и хотел узнать, как правильно надо строить проект.

Про поток. Есть класс `SerialPort`, в главной активности я создаю объект этого класса и `InputStream`, через который я буду вычитывать буфер `UART`. После этого я создаю поток, в котором организую цикл `while (!isInterrupted())` и в этом цикле через `InputStream` вычитываю буфер и обрабатываю полученные данные.
Так вот вопрос: а как можно все это сделать через процесс (если можно пример кода), как передать данные?

Comment: А можете немного подробнее описать, что именно делает этот поток? Может, есть возможность поток перенести в Service? А каждая Activity просто будет к этому Service биндиться. И таким образом поток будет жить вне Activity, но сможет передавать данные в них.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поток надо посадить в `Service`:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
private final IBinder binder = new MyServiceBinder();
private Thread myThread=null; //наш поток

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    myThread=new MyThread();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Starting service="+this.toString());
    if(!myThread.isAlive())
        myThread.start();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder; //грубо говоря получаем ссылку на сервис
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(myThread!=null) {
        myThread.forceStop(); //останавливаем поток
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class MyServiceBinder extends Binder
{
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
}
```

Следующий шаг - в классе `Application` запускаем сервис и получаем на него ссылку:

```
public final class MyApplication extends Application {

private MyService myService;
private Intent myServiceIntent;

/**
* Helper class to handle Service binding
*/
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service connected");
        MyService.MyServiceBinder b = (MyService.MyServiceBinder) binder;
        myService = b.getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service disconnected");
        myService = null;
    }
};

public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   myServiceIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
   this.getApplicationContext().startService(myServiceIntent);
   boolean flag=this.getApplicationContext().bindService(myServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   if(!flag)
        Log.i(TAG, "Can't bind to Service");
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "Service bound");    }
}
```

Не забыть задекларировать сервис и аппликацию в манифесте:

```
<application
    android:name="mypackage.MyApplication"
    >
   <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label=""/>
```

В итоге после всех этих манипуляций имеем ссылочку на наш `Service` в виде переменной `myService`, внутри которого живет наш поток. Далее уже можно рисовать разные геттеры/сеттеры в `MyService` для манипуляцией с потоком - получения от него инфы и проч. При этом `Service` живет сам по себе вне зависимости от `Activity`.

**Update**

[[@selya](/users/26342/selya)](/users/26342/selya) `bindService()` должен в идеале вызываться 1 раз и подсоединении сервиса. Дальше у вас есть ссылка на Java объект, с которым можно делать все что угодно, в частности передать в сервис ссылку на текущий `Activity` - правда это плохая (очень плохая идея), поскольку жизненный цикл `Activity` специфический и легко можно нарваться утечку ресурсов.

Дипломированные способы общения из `Service` к `Activity` - это:

1. Через `Intent` при вызове `Activity` - работает, к несчастью, только 1 раз при  создании `Activity`.
2. Через Broadcast - правда, Broadcast получат все приложения в системе, так что с точки зрения ресурсоемкости это не айс.
3. Через `LocalBroadcast` типа:

   `private void sendMessage() {
      Intent intent = new Intent("myEvent");
      intent.putExtra("myMessage", "myData");
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
   }`
4. Через `Handler` с использованием [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) - то есть созданием кастомного обработчика сообщений.

Как-то так.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ а если поток должен быть инициатором передачи данных, пришла команда на подсвечивание текста, как поток передает данные в активность?
И еще, если я создал другую активность, то в ней то нужно только boolean flag=this.getApplicationContext().bindService(myServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); сделать или еще и private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()? И какой активности будут передаваться данные из потока?

Comment: @selya значит нужно делать через callback, подписываемся, когда у активити срабатывается метод onResume, и отписываемся в методе onPause

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ насколько я понял, мы в Activity имеем ссылку на поток и можем выполнять с ним различные манипуляции. А как из потока передать данные в текущую Activity? И подписываемся и отписываемся это bindService и unbindService?

Comment: @selya см. апдейт